# Eclipse OpenNLP Java API

Tags: java, eclipse, opennlp

I was trying to use OpenNLP to analyze text content. But when I use the code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-sent.bin");
```

there are red wavy lines under `FileInputStream`. It says Type mismatch, cannot convert from `FileInputStream` to `InputStream`. I have imported some jar packages, but I still don't know how to fix it. Is that concerned with environmental variables issue?

Imports:

```
import org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
```

Comment: This is 2015; use `Files.newInputStream` instead.

Comment: Could show your imports? Just the ones that say `InputStream` or `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Hi, thank you. But where should I put it? like InputStream is =Files.newInputStream ("bin")?

Comment: You would edit your post and click the `{}` button (insert code)

Comment: Well, it can't convert that. You're intending to use java.io.InputStream there but have an import for something else. You'll have to use the fully qualified InputStream class name on that line.

Comment: Hi, thank you ,but the document say so: https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong import. Delete the line `import org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable.InputStream;` and replace with `import java.io.InputStream;`.